# Is a bad NFS mount preventing a clean boot?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, mount, nfs, fstab

I'm on Ubuntu server 11.10 (x86) and I basically ran into this problem as this: https://serverfault.com/questions/56588/unmount-a-nfs-mount-where-the-nfs-server-has-disappeared

The `umount` command didn't work, so I tried to just use the ol' reboot. Now the machine gets an error when booting:

```
FS-Cache:netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
<two minutes later>
init: udevtrigger post-stop process (345) terminated with status 1
```

I tried booting in recovery mode so I could just comment out the bad NFS mount in my `/etc/fstab` file, but I wasn't able to write the changes.

I basically just want to get the machine booting properly again so that I can erase the bad mount point, either order is fine. This assumes that the FS-Cache error is due to the bad NFS mount, and that might be a poor assumption.

What are my options here?

Comment: try adding `nofail` to the list of options associated with the NFS drive in your `fstab` file.  This will prevent an error from occurring if the drive cannot be mounted at boot.

Comment: So I got into recovery mode and ran `mount -o remount,rw /` which allowed me to get rid of my bad NFS mounts in `/etc/fstab`, but now my boot (in non-recovery) has seemingly gotten worse -- I get no output on the screen after selecting normal boot from the GRUB menu!

Comment: @s g, do you have `quiet` as a kernel parameter in your GRUB config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got into recovery mode and ran `mount -o remount,rw /` which allowed me to get rid of my bad NFS mounts in `/etc/fstab` (and I prevented further issues by adding the `intr` option to the NFS entries), but then my boot (in non-recovery) seemingly got worse -- I got no output on the screen after selecting normal boot from the GRUB menu!

I then added `nomodeset` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` boot option list and everything worked.

I have no idea how those two were related, but that's what fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In fstab try to use the option "_netdev" so that it reads something like the following. This will ensure that networking is up before trying to mount. This is though not nessesarily the solution for your problem, but could help solve it.

```
server:/remote/export /local/directory rw,_netdev 0 0
```